# Some parts of a webpage is empty when try to scrape

Tags: python-2.7, security, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib2

I'm trying to scrape a web page: http://www.rrk.ir/News/ShowNews.aspx?Code=12099110 as you see it contains some Persian characters. I tried to do it with both urllib2 and requests modules of Python. But the problem is that the main part of the html code is empty in the result. This part is exactly after   `<div class="Jus" style="font-family: Tahoma !important;">` which is in Persian. Is it because of the website security? and how it can be solved? My code to do so is:

```
r = requests.get('http://www.rrk.ir/News/ShowNews.aspx?Code=12099110')
result = r.text.encode("utf-8")
print result
```

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, it appears to be security. Try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver  # to scrape
import lxml                     # to parse/query

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.rrk.ir/News/ShowNews.aspx?Code=12099110')

tree=lxml.html.fromstring(driver.page_source)

tree.xpath('//div[@class="Jus"]')[0].text_content()

driver.close()
```

You'll have to install:

```
pip install lxml
pip install selenium
```